# Error: " 'float' object is not subscriptable" whenever I try to print certain values from a list of averafes

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I created two variables that give the amount of words in a given context that are both positive and negative respectively within a couple of years. The following code is just that:

```
NEGSCORE=len(file1)/len(TITLE)*100
POSSCORE=len(file2)/len(TITLE)*100

print(NEGSCORE)
print(POSSCORE)
```

When I try to test the following code to print out a few values within the span of 30 years randomly I am given this error.

```
print(NEGSCORE[0:5], '\n', NEGSCORE[-5:])
print(POSSCORE[25],'\n', POSSCORE[-25])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [240], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # print out a few values
----> 2 print(NEGSCORE[0:5], '\n', NEGSCORE[-5:])
      3 print(POSSCORE[25],'\n', POSSCORE[-25])

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

EDIT:

```
TITLE = ['19900207.txt','19900327.txt', '19900515.txt', '19900703.txt', '19900821.txt', '19901002.txt', '19901113.txt', '19901218.txt', '19910206.txt', '19910326.txt', '19910514.txt', '19910703.txt', '19910820.txt', '19911001.txt', '19911105.txt', '19911217.txt', '19920205.txt', '19920331.txt', '19920519.txt', '19920701.txt', '19920818.txt', '19921006.txt', '19921117.txt', '19921222.txt', '19930203.txt', '19930323.txt', '19930518.txt', '19930707.txt', '19930817.txt', '19930921.txt', '19931116.txt', '19931221.txt', '19940204.txt', '19940322.txt', '19940517.txt', '19940706.txt', '19940816.txt', '19940927.txt', '19941115.txt', '19941220.txt', '19950201.txt', '19950328.txt', '19950523.txt', '19950706.txt', '19950822.txt', '19950926.txt', '19951115.txt', '19951219.txt', '19960130.txt', '19960326.txt', '19960521.txt', '19960702.txt', '19960820.txt', '19960924.txt', '19961113.txt', '19961217.txt', '19970204.txt', '19970325.txt', '19970520.txt', '19970701.txt', '19970819.txt', '19970930.txt', '19971112.txt', '19971216.txt', '19980203.txt', '19980331.txt', '19980519.txt', '19980630.txt', '19980818.txt', '19980929.txt', '19981117.txt', '19981222.txt', '19990202.txt', '19990330.txt', '19990518.txt', '19990629.txt', '19990824.txt', '19991005.txt', '19991116.txt', '19991221.txt', '20000202.txt', '20000321.txt', '20000516.txt', '20000628.txt', '20000822.txt', '20001003.txt', '20001115.txt', '20001219.txt', '20010131.txt', '20010320.txt', '20010515.txt', '20010627.txt', '20010821.txt', '20011002.txt', '20011106.txt', '20011211.txt', '20020130.txt', '20020319.txt', '20020507.txt', '20020626.txt', '20020813.txt', '20020924.txt', '20021106.txt', '20021210.txt', '20030129.txt', '20030318.txt', '20030506.txt', '20030625.txt', '20030812.txt', '20030916.txt', '20031028.txt', '20031209.txt', '20040128.txt', '20040316.txt', '20040504.txt', '20040630.txt', '20040810.txt', '20040921.txt', '20041110.txt', '20041214.txt', '20050202.txt', '20050322.txt', '20050503.txt', '20050630.txt', '20050809.txt', '20050920.txt', '20051101.txt', '20051213.txt', '20060131.txt', '20060328.txt', '20060510.txt', '20060629.txt', '20060808.txt', '20060920.txt', '20061025.txt', '20061212.txt', '20070131.txt', '20070321.txt', '20070509.txt', '20070628.txt', '20070807.txt', '20070918.txt', '20071031.txt', '20071211.txt', '20080130.txt', '20080318.txt', '20080430.txt', '20080625.txt', '20080805.txt', '20080916.txt', '20081029.txt', '20081216.txt', '20090128.txt', '20090318.txt', '20090429.txt', '20090624.txt', '20090812.txt', '20090923.txt', '20091104.txt', '20091216.txt', '20100127.txt', '20100316.txt', '20100428.txt', '20100623.txt', '20100810.txt', '20100921.txt', '20101103.txt', '20101214.txt', '20110126.txt', '20110315.txt', '20110427.txt', '20110622.txt', '20110809.txt', '20110921.txt', '20111102.txt', '20111213.txt', '20120125.txt', '20120313.txt', '20120425.txt', '20120620.txt', '20120801.txt', '20120913.txt', '20121024.txt', '20121212.txt', '20130130.txt', '20130320.txt', '20130501.txt', '20130619.txt', '20130731.txt', '20130918.txt', '20131030.txt', '20131218.txt', '20140129.txt', '20140319.txt', '20140430.txt', '20140618.txt', '20140730.txt', '20140917.txt', '20141029.txt', '20141217.txt', '20150128.txt', '20150318.txt', '20150429.txt', '20150617.txt', '20150729.txt', '20150917.txt', '20151028.txt', '20151216.txt', '20160127.txt', '20160316.txt', '20160427.txt', '20160615.txt', '20160727.txt', '20160921.txt', '20161102.txt', '20161214.txt', '20170201.txt', '20170315.txt', '20170503.txt', '20170614.txt', '20170726.txt', '20170920.txt', '20171101.txt', '20171213.txt', '20180131.txt', '20180321.txt', '20180502.txt', '20180613.txt', '20180801.txt', '20180926.txt', '20181108.txt', '20181219.txt', '20190130.txt', '20190320.txt', '20190501.txt', '20190619.txt', '20190731.txt', '20190918.txt', '20191030.txt', '20191211.txt', '20200129.txt', '20200315.txt', '20200429.txt', '20200610.txt', '20200729.txt', '20200916.txt', '20201105.txt', '20201216.txt', '20210127.txt', '20210317.txt', '20210428.txt', '20210616.txt', '20210728.txt', '20210922.txt', '20211103.txt', '20211215.txt']
print(TITLE[0]) # FIRST FILE NAME
print(TITLE[-1]) # LAST FILE NAME
print(type(TITLE),type(TITLE[0]))


 19900207.txt
 20211215.txt
 <class 'list'> <class 'str'>
```

Essentially I am obtaining a dataset that contains 256 negative scores (call this variable "NEGSCORE") and a dataset of 256 positive scores (call this variable "POSSCORE"). The first element of NEGSCORE for example, corresponds to the negative score calculated using the 19900207 FOMC minutes, and the last element corresponds to the negative score calculated using the 20211215 FOMC minutes. The Formula used is (count of negative words)/(count of total words) *100. The total words is each individual text file in TITLE and negative words is in a separate text file that has a len of 19.

Comment: `NEGSCORE` is a number, so what are you expecting `NEGSCORE[0:5]` to mean?  The only variables visible in your code that might be meaningful to slice are `file1`, `file2`, and `TITLE`.

Comment: Let me edit the code to give context to the TITLE variable. Essentially however I am trying to get a score/number from  a zipped file containing 30 text files that I created a  a "positive" or "negative" sentiment score.

Comment: The error is with NEGSCORE.  The edit does not address that variable at all.  I don't understand why you think TITLE is important to the error...

Comment: I added further context with NEGSCORE

Comment: There is no "first element of NEGSCORE" - it's a single number, that you calculated.  `file1` appears to be the actual list of negative scores.

Comment: That is somewhat the case as file 1's code is "file1=Text('1.6_LM_negative.txt')" with that being the actual title of the text file

Comment: `NEGSCORE=len(file1)/len(TITLE)*100` This variable is an integer.  Why did you expect it to be a list?